# Generating a new project on Moovweb

Tags: moovweb

I'm having a tough time creating a new project for Moovweb.  I'm getting this error, but don't see where to add SSH keys within moovweb:

"ERROR: None of the SSH keys on this machine are associated with your moovweb account. Please use moov login, then try again."

Comment: What platform (Windows, Mac, Linux) are you on? Windows has known issues with SSH keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383177/permission-denied-publickey-errors-on-windows-when-using-moovweb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens if your ssh key is named something other than the default `id_rsa`

You can see what keys are associated with the ssh-agent by typing this command

```
ssh-add -l
```

If the key you have uploaded to Moovweb is not in that list, you can add it with

```
ssh-add <path to key>
```

For example,

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```