# generate new project failed on Windows when using Moovweb

Tags: github, moovweb

I am new to the moovweb and i want to create new project using movweb. But when I tried to create new app using **moov generate reddit reddit.com** using cmd  on windows
I got following error:

```
$ moov generate reddit redit.com                 
  * Running environment checks.    
  | Verifying that git is installed...OK                
  | Checking that current reddit directory doesn't exist...OK   
  * Registering project with MoovCloud.  
  | Authenticating with MoovCloud.  
  | Checking for git access...Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/amarjeet/.ssh/i
   d_rsa':

 ERROR: None of the SSH keys on this machine are associated with your moovweb acc
 ount. Please use moov login, then try again.
```

Comment: I tried moov login..login is happening fine. and ssh also getting added to moovweb cloud.

Comment: I tried to delete old ssh key and add new ssh key but also no luck..

Comment: What is the output from moov login?

Comment: $ moov login
Please enter your MoovCloud credentials:
Email: amarjeet.blr@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):


*** There is a new version of the Moovweb SDK available for download. ***
Found existing public key: C:\Users\amarjeet\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
Uploading public key...
Successfully uploaded public key id_rsa.pub as 'amarjeet.blr@gmail.com'
You are now ready to push projects to MoovCloud!..                its adding ssh key ..

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730242/generating-a-new-project-on-moovweb

Comment: @Ishan , i tried that .. But no luck

Comment: I think This issue is related to firwall security , Can you please give me some pointer which site and port should be accessible for moov generate command.

Comment: Hmmm...how about filing a ticket at help.moovweb.com and we can help debug this in greater detail?

Comment: Already filed ticket at help.moovweb.com. waiting for reply

Comment: Talked to our support team and it sounds like this was an issue with a firewall on the machine preventing access to port 22 for moovweb.com domains.